# TCL command - string trim

Tags: tcl

I was using the command 'string trimright' to trim my string but I found that this command trims more than required.

My expression is "**dssss.dcsss**" If I use string trim command to trim the last few characters ".dcsss", it trims the entire string. How can I deal with this?

Command:

```
     set a [string trimright "dcssss.dcsss" ".dcsss"]
     puts $a
```

Intended output:

```
    dcsss
```

Actual output

```
    ""
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `string trimright` command treats its (optional) last argument as a *set* of characters to remove (and so `.dcsss` is the same as `sdc.` to it), just like `string trim` and `string trimleft` do; indeed, `string trim` is just like using both `string trimright` and `string trimleft` in succession. This makes it unsuitable for what you are trying to do; to remove a suffix if it is present, you can use several techniques:

```
# It looks like we're stripping a filename extension...
puts [file rootname "dcssss.dcsss"]
```

```
# Can use a regular expression if we're careful...
puts [regsub {\.dcsss$} "dcssss.dcsss" {}]
```

```
# Do everything by hand...
set str "dcssss.dcsss"
if {[string match "*.dcsss" $str]} {
    set str [string range $str 0 end-6]
}
puts $str
```

If what you're doing really is filename manipulation, like it looks like, do use the first of these options. The `file` command has some really useful commands for working with filenames in a cross-platform manner in it.